# How to call a function related to a specific UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ibaction

I'm very new to Swift and Xcode so please bear with me.

I have a `UIViewController` for a Create Account screen which has 4 `UITextFields`. The first 3 can be edited fine when the keyboard appears but the last one needs the `UIView` to be pushed so it is visible.

I have installed the Cocoapod `IHKeyboardAvoiding` which is working great, only when I tap on the top three UITextfields the screen also pushes up. The pseudo code for this is: 'When confirm password textfield is tapped the keyboard push should occur. When all other textfields are tapped, no keyboard push should occur.'

I'm unsure how to implement the pseudo code into actual swift code. I've created an IBAction for the confirm password textfield and implemented the keyboard push code within it. This works but as soon as the confirm password textfield is tapped and then another textfield is tapped the keyboard push gets applied to all the textfields. I'm thinking that the function needs to be called within the viewDidLoad but you can't have an IBAction function within viewDidLoad.

What would be the best way to call the function?

```
import UIKit
import IHKeyboardAvoiding

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var avoidingView: UIView!

@IBAction func confirmPassword(_ sender: UITextField) {
      KeyboardAvoiding.avoidingView = self.avoidingView
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, you don't need to use cocoapod for something so simple. It literally is 2 lines of code to do this without cocoapod. I can show you how if you are interested.

Comment: Sure @DevKyle I would be interested in how you would approach this

Answer (score 1):

1. First you want to set your class to conform to **UITextFieldDelegate**:

So in your case,

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

2. Then, set the tag as CodeBender describes above. You only have to do this for the 4th textfield that you DO want to move the screen for.
3. Set all 4 textfields' delegate to self. For example, if your textfield are named one, two, three, four

   ```
   one.delegate = self
   two.delegate = self
   three.delegate = self
   four.delegate = self
   //Change the return key to Done so that tapping it dismisses keyboard
   four.returnKeyType = .done
   ```
4. Add the following to your class:

   ```
   func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

       if textField.tag == 1 {

           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

               self.view.frame.origin.y -= 224

           }) 

       }
   }



   func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

       textField.resignFirstResponder()

       if textField.tag == 1 {

           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

               self.view.frame.origin.y += 224

           }) 

       }

   }
   ```

That should do it, let me know if you run into anything!

Answer (score 0):

Take your password textfield and apply a tag value to it like this:

```
passwordTextfield.tag = 1
```

If you have not connected the textfield to your view controller, you can also set the value in your storyboard file:

[image]

Then, in your `confirmPassword` function, do a check against the tag value:

```
if (sender.tag == 1) { ... }
```

Comment: I added the 1 tag in the storyboard file but the code didn't work. Is this how I should be writing it? 
`@IBAction func confirmPassword(_ sender: UITextField) {
        if (sender.tag == 1){
          KeyboardAvoiding.avoidingView = self.avoidingView
        }
    }`

Comment: @EmmaCampbell That looks right. You can place breakpoints in that function to see the values coming in to make sure that they are correct.

Comment: this code works, but once the confirm password textfield has been tapped and I tap another textfield the push then gets applied to it as well. Do you have any suggestions on what might be the best way to change it so that the other textfields don't inherit the push?